# Ubuntu won't boot after replacing windows 8 with it

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows, windows-8

I've installed Ubuntu over windows 8 by wiping windows 8 partition. Now I get a recovery screen for Windows even though it's gone. Any tips to fix? I tried *Boot Repair* in Ubuntu live. No luck.

Comment: I would not recommend to "install ubuntu over windows 8 by wiping windows 8 partition"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd format the whole drive and reinstall.

The problem you seem to have is you've left the boot partition of Windows 8 (it's a hidden partition and often missed).  If you have stuff you really love on that computer you can search for that partition using a liveCD and use Gparted to remove the offending partition, but then you'd have to repair grub, which is a pain.

In short **nuke and pave**.

Comment: Thanks guys. So what I did was I re-edit it all. Re-partitioned drive but this time wiped out existing efi boot partition. Then created a new one and it all worked.

Comment: "Nuke 'n pave"!  Couldn't have said it better, thus: upvote!  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I have used tsupergrubdisk (user friendly gui interface) to recover both windows and Ubuntu boot problems  in different scenarios.. http://www.supergrubdisk.org/

I suggest you to try it and check,,, http://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-window-linux-boot-problems-with-super-grub-disk/

www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lkz2Q_F77lM